# Bison: Give left precedence to a rule?

Tags: yacc, bison

With bison i have many %left's (+,*, etc) and a few %right's (=, +=, etc). These are all tokens. Now i have a rule. Its

```
| rval
| AttrData rval
```

The problem is, AttrData rval returns an rval so AttrData 1+1 could either be (AttrData 1) +1 or AttrData (1+1). What i like to do is apply the left rule to AttrData BUT that doesnt work cause it isnt a token. I tried %prec and i get an error about it too.

I can fix it by writing `| AttrData '(' rval ')'` BUT i dont want to do and i rather have the users write `AttrData (1+1)` since most of the time they'll actually mean (AttrData 1)+1.

How do i give the rule left precedence?

The only thing similar i have is else, which i solved by forcing braces for no confusion (if cond { if cond } else )

Answer (score 1):

You can set explicit precedences will may be help you

IF ELSE example

```
%nonassoc LOWER_THAN_ELSE

%nonassoc ELSE

%%
stmt   :    IF expr stmt %prec LOWER_THAN_ELSE ;
       |    IF expr stmt ELSE stmt;
```